# Why does my command not execute immediately unless I use MessageBox.Show()?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am developing a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application that controls a hardware device. I have a button that turns off the device. The click event looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnTurnOff_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles btnTurnOff.Click

    device.SetOff() 'Turn off the device
    system.threading.thread.sleep(2000) 'Pause for 2 seconds
End Sub
```

What is strange is, the device doesn't turn off until after the 2 sec. pause, but if I insert a MessageBox immediately after the SetOff() command then the device turns off immediately, before the 2 sec. pause:

```
Private Sub btnTurnOff_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles btnTurnOff.Click

    device.SetOff() 'turn off the device
    MessageBox.Show("Device is now off")
    system.threading.thread.sleep(2000) 'Pause for 2 seconds
End Sub
```

Why would this code behave in this way?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` is blocking, so it won't proceed to the `Thread.Sleep` until you click "OK".

Answer (score 2):

Because you are sleeping the thread...

So the programs do nothing for two seconds. Adding the message box make the program go on, and after that, the thread goes to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The thread does nothing while sleeping, it sort of hagning there.
When you show the message box, the thread is still running.

Try a quick test, something like

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
    system.threading.thread.sleep(20)
Next
```

A better way would be

```
Do While [Device Is On]
    system.threading.thread.sleep(100)
Loop
```

An even better way would be if device.SetOff() would call an event when it finish what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the two and put the Sleep before the MessageBox.

Comment: Why? Consider placing more information for the OP to follow up on.